# How to remove "WordPress News" feed downloading?

Tags: dashboard

A fresh WordPress install just downloaded 619 kB large feed used for the "WordPress News" widget on the dashboard. This renders things like `wp option list` useless as the longest line (!) is 600,000 characters wide.

I'm looking for a way to completely suppress this functionality.

Comment: sorry, but no real idea what are you talking about

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% certain if you are looking for a way to remove the Meta-boxes?

If so, following plugin could solve your 'issue'.
*(please backup and so on ...)*

```
/**
 * Remove Dashboard widgets
 *
 * @version Wordpress 4.6.1
 */
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse241195_disable_dashboard_widgets' );
function wpse241195_disable_dashboard_widgets()
{
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_incoming_links', 'dashboard', 'normal' );   // Incoming Links
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_plugins', 'dashboard', 'normal' );          // Plugins
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_quick_press', 'dashboard', 'side' );        // Quick Press
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_recent_drafts', 'dashboard', 'side' );      // Recent Drafts
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_primary', 'dashboard', 'side' );            // WordPress blog
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_secondary', 'dashboard', 'side' );          // Other WordPress News    
    remove_action( 'welcome_panel', 'wp_welcome_panel' );                   // Remove WordPress Welcome Panel
}
```

It is the complete list, little overdone but as said, adjust to ownwishes.
**Note:**
This function removes them completely, so if you not wish that you should create a function to just hide them *(which not removes them and imho it still will be loading the news feed and more)*

> See [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_dashboard_setup) for more information

Comment: That is perfect. `remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_primary', 'dashboard', 'side' );` worked great.